# Verticaly fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working in a page that has a min-width of 1124px, so each time the browser is smaller than 1124px, the page's content can be scrooled horizontaly, instead of a responsive transition.

http://seluno.jp/

I wonder if I can fix the header only vertically, so when the browser is smaller than 1124px, the header will be scrolled horizontally with the rest of the pages content, but when the page is scrolled vertically, the header is fixed on top.

```
body {
 min-width: 1124px;
}

header {
 position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: tie a trigger to your scroll event and keep top of header always at 0.

Comment: Why you don't use `@media` at all?

Comment: I wish I could, but it must be done like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: sticky;` so it stays fixed on top but allowing horizontal scroll like this:

```
#header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Example:

```css
body {
  min-width: 1124px;
}

#header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Just to fill space on screen */
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, white, blue);
}
.content {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```